# Question Regarding Series and Parallel Circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, parallel, series

Stack Exchange members, I am new to this stack, so please allow any formatting errors. My question is that what is a 'bank' in the following statements:

'3 out of 12 resistors in one parallel bank'

'2 resistors in a bank that is series with 1 resistance'

I personally think that it is a synonym for a branch in a parallel circuit, but what are your thoughts?

Comment: I think in this context, "bank" is just being used synonymous to the common word "group". The word bank can have technical definitions in electronics, especially when referring to memory banks in an MCU. But in this context, I think bank is just being used as common vernacular.

Comment: Context may be significant but you haven't given us any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bank seems to be equivalent to "parallel" eg 2 resistors in parallel that is in series with another resistor.